# てほしい usage with more than 2 people, particles に and が

Tags: grammar

The context is this.
A girl who was always alone when she was a kid had a butler who was called すわの who is now far away from her. She just saved a boy from drowning and she feels good about that because the boy and his brother thanked her for that.

> すわの、あんたがいてくれたなら聞いてほしかった。
> 本当自分でも分かんないんだけど、あの時なんかこう胸が[暖]{あった}かくなったんだ。

The translation is

> If you were here I would ask you.
> I do not know by myself but I feel warm inside.

Is the translation wrong?
Isn't てほしい used when you want someone to do something?

I would translate it

> Suwano, If you were here I would have wanted you to listen.
> I can't really understand by myself, but that time my heart became warm like this.

Also can someone explain me how this form works?
Could I use the particle が in a sentence like this

> I want A to teach B English
> 私はＡにＢに英語を教えてほしい
> or
> 私はＡがＢに英語を教えてほしい

I know the first one is correct, but what about the second one?

Another user made this example to me in a previous thread. It was this

> 彼に英語を教えてほしい。
>
> This sentence can be translated as two ways.
>
> A. I want him to teach someone English.
>
> A' （彼女が私に英語を教えてくれると言っているけれど、私は）彼に英語を教えてほしい。
>
> B. I want you to teach him English.
>
> B'. （あなたは英語を教えるのがうまいから、あなたが）彼に英語を教えてほしい。

In B' could it become

> B'（あなたは英語を教えるのがうまいから、僕はあなたに）彼に英語を教えてほしい。

Also how can I know if 聞いてほしい is *want someone to listen* or *want someone to ask*?

Edit.
Nothing at all was referring to something I wrote before but it was just confusing so I edited it out.

Edit 2.
For those who want to know the source for the context it's Binbougami Ga!? Episode 3 about minute 19.30

Comment: ～たがりたい doesn't make sense; ～たがる means 'giving the impression of wanting to ~'. Someone could say 僕に聞きたい事があるんだって 'He/She/It/They said they wanted to ask me something,' for an example of your thing.

Comment: Thanks.
I edited my question since that was not I wanted to ask and it was just confusing.
You still cleared a doubt of mine with たがる though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> あんたがいてくれたなら聞{き}いてほしかった。

This sentence might NOT be translated as ''...**I** would ask you.'' It is no wonder you doubt the translation.  
*聞いてほしい* means that the speaker wants someone to do *聞く*.  
Conversely, if the translation were correct, the original must be *聞きたかった* or *尋{たず}ねたかった*.

*聞く* can mean either *listen* or *ask*. Also, it can be translated as *follow* or *obey* in other contexts. 
It depends on the context which meaning does ''聞く'' express. The root concept of 聞く seems to know by receiving some sound.

---

> I want A to teach B English. ／ A=あなた　B=彼 
>   
>   1.(?) 私{わたし}は、A**に**Bに英語{えいご}を教{おし}えてほしい。／ (?)私はあなた**に**彼に英語を教えてほしい。 
>   2. 私は、A**が**Bに英語を教えてほしい。／私はあなた**が**彼に英語を教えてほしい。  
>   3. 私は、A**から**Bに英語を教えてほしい。／私はあなた**から**彼に英語を教えてほしい。

Example #1 is not wrong grammatically, but the meaning is a bit unclear because ''someone+に'' follows the same form. 
So, you'd better say as #2 or #3.

cf. ''から'' is used to indicate the subject when the verb is 伝{つた}える, 話{はな}す, 言{い}う, 教{おし}える, 渡{わた}す, 送{おく}る, and so on.　
For examples,

> 私はあなた**から**彼にこれを渡してほしい。  
>   I want you to hand this to him.